# Using Admin to manage model fields

Tags: django, entity-attribute-value

I want to use django-eav to implement Entitiy Attribute Value in my Django Project.

What should I do, to let admins to use Admin site to add or modify models? Is there an app for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that django-dynamo app is the thing I was looking for.

https://bitbucket.org/schacki/django-dynamo/